# Update class property inside a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to update the `this.bar` property of my class on click event.
The problem is that `this` inside the `click` function is not the same `this` of the class.

```
export class Chart {

  constructor() {
    this.bar;
  }

  showChart() {
    ...
    let group = svg.selectAll('g').data(data).enter().append('g');
    group.append('rect')
      .on('click', function(d) {
      // Here I want `this.bar = d`
      });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable to `this` in the block before the function:

```
export class Chart {

  constructor() {
    this.bar;
  }

  showChart() {
    ...
    let self = this;
    let group = svg.selectAll('g').data(data).enter().append('g');
    group.append('rect')
      .on('click', function(d) {
          self.bar=d;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define `this` inside the `showChart()` function:

```
export class Chart {

  constructor() {
    this.bar;
  }

  showChart() {
    ...
    var th = this;      // Here you define it
    let group = svg.selectAll('g').data(data).enter().append('g');
    group.append('rect')
      .on('click', function(d) {
          th.bar = d;      
      });

  }
}
```